# PyQt5: One button is differently shaped

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I using PyQt5.8 to create a horizontal layout of buttons to be displayed in the center of the window. However, I am having a display issue when the program is run.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)     

        self.setWindowTitle('Test Title')

        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        for n in range(10):

            btn = QPushButton(str(n))                
            btn.pressed.connect(lambda x = n: self.my_custom_fn(x))                
            layout.addWidget(btn)

        widget = QWidget()            
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def my_custom_fn(self, a):
        print (a)
```

My issue is when I run the program, the '1' button is a different shape than the rest of the buttons.

[image]

Why is this? If I expand the window, the '1' button matches the format of the other buttons. What can I do to prevent the '1' button from becoming 'square'?

Comment: I think the button is pressed?

Comment: Is that the complete code?

Comment: I took the photo when I wasn't pressing any buttons. Additionally, 1 should be printed if it was pressed. No, I took out a bit of it (the imports and creating the QApplication, creating and showing the window and starting the event loop).

Comment: You have tried running it back, it seems like a very strange behavior.

Comment: Running it back?

Comment: Have you tried running this code on another platform? Is the problem still there?

Comment: I only have my mac to run it on.